# Adding Overlays to Videos export as a video in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-mediacodec

So i have a video for eg. a race car video and i created a overlay view (transparent relative layout) which includes some progress bar related to speed and performance now i need to export full video as seen in this view so can anyone please help me i have gone through ffmpeg,opencv but no success.

[Similar Ios Overlay](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos)

Comment: Which overlay ?

Comment: And show the code you have, please.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Here is what I got.. you want to export a video, that is being played on the screen. What are you using to play the video ?

Comment: i have a view on top of video i want to export the video with that view embedded on top of that video

Comment: This is an interesting and hard problem. None of the posted solutions will work as-is. The explanation is too detailed to fit within a comment. Have you tried doing it outside the view loop. If the overlay is static, then its a relatively easier with ffmpeg command. But if the overlay is dynamic(e.g. subtitles), then the ffmpeg command is complicated.  Doing it in the view loop is not a practical solution, unless the video is from a live stream.
A good example of something similar is [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika). You can use relevant parts that source on your app.

Comment: i have seen grafika also but it gives an example of recording a surfaceview in my case the data is speed of car and its a viewgroup not a single view (surfaceview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to achieve using opencv org.bytedeco.javacpp, i used FFmpegFrameGrabber for garbing frame and FFmpegFrameRecorder recording this images back to mp4 with the same audio codex.

> Dependencies needed:
>
> ```
>     compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.4'
>     compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.0-1.4', classifier: 'android-arm'
>     compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.4.1-1.4', classifier: 'android-arm'
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use OpenCV or ffmpeg to accomplish this task, but it seems like they might not be the right tool for this task. OpenCV is great for advanced video processing, and under the hood it uses ffmpeg for decoding and encoding capabilities. ffmpeg is great when you need to support a wide variety of media formats. For ffmpeg you could try to run run it as a standalone process, but this is less than ideal for permission issues and error handling. You can also write your own Android NDK API that incorporates ffmpeg, but this could be a lot of effort. Assuming your required output media format is [supported by Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html), the easiest path is to use the Android MediaCodec libraries.

Take a look at [this test code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecodeEditEncodeTest.java) from Google that shows how to decode, edit, and encode. You can decode the video file into a SurfaceTexture. For the editing part you will use OpenGL ES to do the overlay. The overlay image can be uploaded to a texture and drawn over the video frame SurfaceTexture. Once the scene is drawn, the outputted texture can be sent to the MediaCodec encoder. This can all be done in the export process and doesn't necessarily need to be need be associated with your viewable video and transparent relative layout.

Answer (score 2):

For decoding video to bitmap and encoding bitmap back to mp4 video you can use [jcodec](http://jcodec.org).

```
SequenceEncoder sequenceEncoder = new SequenceEncoder(new File(pathToSaveVideo));
```

Perform these steps in a loop

1. Extract bitmaps of each frame of video
2. Combine with overlay bitmap

   ```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(backgroundBitmap);
    Paint rectpaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    int width = overlayBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = overlayBitmap.getHeight();
    Rect des = new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, src, des, rectpaint);
   ```
3. Encode it back into a video

   ```
   sequenceEncoder.encodeImage(backgroundBitmap);
   ```

Finally finish the encoder after loop

`sequenceEncoder.finish()`